# appending list names to columns of data.frames within

Tags: r, purrr

I have imported a list of data.frames `in1`

```
in1 <- file_paths [1:3] %>% 
  set_names(basename(.) %>% 
              gsub("_R1_001.bg.gz.bismark.cov.gz", "", .) %>% 
              gsub("CpG_", "", .)) %>% 
  map(readr::read_tsv, n_max = 3, 
      col_names = c("chr", "start", "end", "score", "ref", "alt"))
```

A small example of `in1` (few files, few rows) looks like this:

```
$`OB_0120-53T_S26`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  chr   start   end score   ref   alt
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 chr1  19190 19190   100     1     0
2 chr1  19249 19249   100     1     0
3 chr1  19274 19274   100     1     0

$`OB_0120-55T_S25`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  chr   start   end score   ref   alt
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 chr1  17479 17479   100     2     0
2 chr1  17484 17484   100     2     0
3 chr1  17493 17493   100     2     0

$`OB_0120-56T_S36`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  chr   start   end score   ref   alt
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 chr1  17479 17479   100     1     0
2 chr1  17484 17484   100     1     0
3 chr1  17493 17493   100     1     0
```

I aim to join them into one larger data.frame eg.

`%>% reduce(full_join, by= c("chr", "start", "end"))`

However first I want to append the list name of each element to the "score" "ref" and "alt" column names.

**So the desired first element should look like this...**

```
$`OB_0120-53T_S26`
    # A tibble: 3 x 6
      chr   start   end OB_0120-53T_S26.score   OB_0120-53T_S26.ref   OB_0120-53T_S26.alt
      <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
    1 chr1  19190 19190   100     1     0
    2 chr1  19249 19249   100     1     0
    3 chr1  19274 19274   100     1     0
```

I have tried use `set_names` but I do not know how to get the singular name of the list element I am getting the whole vector of names **and hence this is wrong.**

```
in1 %>% map(set_names, c("chr", "start", "end", paste0(names(.), c(".score", ".ref", ".alt"))))

$`OB_0120-53T_S26`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  chr   start   end `OB_0120-53T_S26.score` `OB_0120-55T_S25.ref` `OB_0120-56T_S36.alt`
  <chr> <int> <int>                   <int>                 <int>                 <int>
1 chr1  19190 19190                     100                     1                     0
2 chr1  19249 19249                     100                     1                     0
3 chr1  19274 19274                     100                     1                     0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry after puzzling at this for 2 hours I found a solution (below) a few minutes after posting...

Answer (score 0):

...actually this works

```
  in1 %>% 
      map2( ., names(.), 
      ~set_names(.x, c("chr", "start", "end", paste0(.y, c(".score", ".ref", ".alt")))))

$`OB_0120-53T_S26`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  chr   start   end `OB_0120-53T_S26.score` `OB_0120-53T_S26.ref` `OB_0120-53T_S26.alt`
  <chr> <int> <int>                   <int>                 <int>                 <int>
1 chr1  19190 19190                     100                     1                     0
2 chr1  19249 19249                     100                     1                     0
3 chr1  19274 19274                     100                     1                     0

$`OB_0120-55T_S25`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  chr   start   end `OB_0120-55T_S25.score` `OB_0120-55T_S25.ref` `OB_0120-55T_S25.alt`
  <chr> <int> <int>                   <int>                 <int>                 <int>
1 chr1  17479 17479                     100                     2                     0
2 chr1  17484 17484                     100                     2                     0
3 chr1  17493 17493                     100                     2                     0
```